# Получение допустимого размера Shared Objects в ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Всем привет!
Пишу на AS3 подгрузчик JS, CSS библиотек и объектов, очень бы хотелось чтобы всё это счастье кешировалось в Shared Objects т.к. с Shared Objects работать легче чем с простым кешом браузера. Все файлы весят около 7-8 Мб, но стандартный размер Shared Objects всего 10 Кб, **хотелось бы чтобы при входе на сайт если текущий разрешённый размер Shared Objects менее к примеру 1 Мб - пользователю выходило описание как можно его увеличить, но дело в том что найти способ как получить этот разрешённый размер я так и не нашёл**.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("test");
so.flush( 100000 );
```

Потребует от пользователя, увеличить SO до 1 мб.